# JBoss 7 POJO Service

Tags: jboss7.x, pojo

I'm looking to create my jboss 7 application, writing it as a 'service' (as in [the documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/ejb3/app-server/tutorial/service/service.html)).  However I'm struggling to make progress.  From what I've gathered `org.jboss.annotation.ejb.Service` may be depreciated?  I get "org.jboss.annotation cannot be resolved" errors.

I'm currently using JBoss 7, Eclipse and JBossTools for my development environment.  (I'm not intending on using Swing or any other frameworks, as I'm trying to get the jboss bits nailed before I move onto them)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this info can help.

Classloading model changed in JBoss 7. It hides much stuff that's not explicitly declared.

You have to get familar with these links:

https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Developer+Guide#DeveloperGuide-HowtoresolveClassNotFoundExceptionsandNoCLassDefFoundErrors

https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Class+Loading+in+AS7